# A dense open set is locally compact in a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I've been stuck on this problem for a while:

Prove that a dense subset of a compact Hausdorff space is open iff it is locally compact.

I've solved $(\Longleftarrow)$ (it's actually been posted before) but for the other side I have no idea. I was trying to find a relatively compact open set for each point (in our dense set). That is because we know that X is locally compact iff for each point there is an open and relatively compact set containing it.

Comment: The forward implication follows from the standard fact that an open subset of a locally compact Hausdorff space is again locally compact.

Comment: OK I'm blind ! I didn't notice that our space is compact as well as being T_2 so I was trying to prove it without using the fact that our space is compact. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the space and $U$ be the open dense subset. For any point $x \in U$, consider the open set $U$. Then, $\bar{U} = X$ (since it is dense) and hence compact. In other words, $U$ is locally compact.

Answer (score 2):

Let $O$ be an open subset of your $X$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $O$ and $x \in O$. Then $U$ is also open in $X$ and as $X$ is regular (being compact Hausdorff) there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ so that $x \in V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U$. It follows that $\overline{V}$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$ inside $U$ (and inside $O$) so $O$ is locally compact QED.

The density of the subspace is irrelevant and for $X$ be only need it to be a locally compact Hausdorff space, not even compact.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is compact and $A$ is an open subset of $X$, take $a\in A$. Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $a$ with $V\subset A$; you want to prove that $V$ contains a compact neighborhhod of $a$. You can assume without loss of generality that $V$ is open. So, since $V$ is open in $A$ and $A$ is open in $X$, $V$ is open in $X$, and so $V^\complement$ is closed. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $\{a\}$ is closed, and $X$ is normal. Therefore there are open sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that $\{a\}\subset A_1(\iff a\in A_1)$, that $V^\complement\subset A_2$ and that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$. So, $A_2^{\,\complement}\supset A_1$, and therefore $A_2^{\,\complement}$ is a compact neighborhood of $a$. But $A_2^{\,\complement}\subset V$.